# Pulling API Data results in undefined index

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to pull weather data from the Weatherstack API and all seems to be working except for when I echo the data.

```
<?php
$searchLocation = 'Melbourne';

$searchQuery = http_build_query([
    'access_key' => 'REDACTED',
    'query' => $searchLocation,
]);

$httpRequest = curl_init(sprintf('%s?%s', 'https://api.weatherstack.com/current', $searchQuery));
curl_setopt($httpRequest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$responseData = curl_exec($httpRequest);
curl_close($httpRequest);

$result = json_decode($responseData, true);

echo "Current temperature in $searchLocation is {$result['current']['temperature']}℃", PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Whenever I try to get the output it says "undefined index current on line 29". I'm not really sure what's going on here as I haven't run into this before.

Comment: Use var_dump on the $responseData and see what is actually in it.

Comment: Please provide logs, stack traces, or anything representing the execution. Also, I would suggest to validate the output of sprintf (is the result string as expected?) as well as the content of $searchQuery

Answer (score 0):

[N:B: You have not supplied a valid API Access Key. [Technical Support: support@apilayer.com]
#Here success return is false. Make sure that, there ['current'] is a valid index of $result.
You have to ensure what kind of indexes are present with $result variable to use.
So, there is no index of result. [Additional: you can see the output of $result variable only by dd($result); before echo in last line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKMyx.png)

Comment: There is an access key but I removed it when I posted the code here

Comment: Ow,, What are you got output through $result variable?

Comment: It says Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: use dd($result); before echo, and if you didn't get any array, you can't use any kind of index. so, make sure first, you have got array through response.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The following line `$httpRequest = curl_init(sprintf('%s?%s', 'https://api.weatherstack.com/current', $searchQuery))` was producing an error as my WeatherStack account didn't support https encryption so I had to change it to http.